# ruby 0.20058343942960624257135598502550788022255447223e2 How to convert to 20

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I encountered this error during unit testing, and I tried using to_i. But this is wrong, how should we solve it

```
        --- expected
        +++ actual
        @@ -1 +1 @@
        -0.20058343942960624257135598502550788022255447223e2
        +20
```

Comment: How does your unit test look like? Why do you expect a floating point value when the actual value is an integer?

Answer (score 2):

For minitest use [assert_in_delta](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/5.9.0/Minitest%2FAssertions:assert_in_delta)

```
assert_in_delta(0.33, 1.0 / 3.0, 0.01)
```

For rspec use [be_within](https://rubydoc.info/github/rspec/rspec-expectations/RSpec%2FMatchers:be_within)

```
expect(1.0 / 3.0).to be_within(0.01).of(0.33)
```